# Converting Enums to Key,Value Pairs

Tags: c#

How to convert Enum to Key,Value Pairs. I have converted it in **C# 3.0** .

```
 public enum Translation
    {
        English,
        Russian,
        French,
        German
    }

   string[] trans = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Translation));

   var v = trans.Select((value, key) =>
   new { value, key }).ToDictionary(x => x.key + 1, x => x.value);
```

In **C# 1.0** What is the way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C# 1...

```
string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Translation));

Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    hashTable[i + 1] = names[i];
}
```

Are you sure you really want a map from *index* to name though? If you're just using integer indexes, why not just use an array or an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Thanks.Just I finished schooling.Learnig C#.I will follow your advice sir.

Comment: If I want to improve my design (coding style) shall i submit my work and ask for opinion or only simple q & a is allowed in this forum?

Comment: Well, specific questions and answers are ideal - but questions related to *small* pieces of code in terms of design, clarity etc are fine. Just don't submit thousands of lines of code in one question :) It also helps if your examples are short and complete, rather than just being part of a big project.

Comment: Sir, i need very clear answer to my question "C# iteration requesting scenario based example" which i just posted.could you help me ,giving precise example?

Answer (score 26):

For C# 3.0 if you have an Enum like this:

```
public enum Translation
{
    English = 1,
    Russian = 2,
    French = 4,
    German = 5
}
```

don't use this:

```
string[] trans = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Translation));

var v = trans.Select((value, key) =>
new { value, key }).ToDictionary(x => x.key + 1, x => x.value);
```

because it will mess up your key (which is an integer).

Instead, use something like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Translation)))
{
    dict.Add((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Translation), name), name);
}
```

Comment: Be warned that in the second example(and I guess the first too if it didn't use indexes) it doesn't support enums with duplicate int values

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really what i was looking for. I couldn't understand the use of Dictionary<> datatype in real project.

Answer (score 8):

I think, this example will help to you.

For example your enum defined like as below:

```
public enum Translation
{
    English,
    Russian,
    French,
    German
}
```

You can use this below code piece for convert enum to **KeyValuePairs**:

```
var translationKeyValuePairs = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Translation))
                                   .Cast<int>()
                                   .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(key: x, value: Enum.GetName(typeof(Translation), x)))
                                   .ToList();
```

Or you can use **Dictionary** like as below:

```
var translationDictionary = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Translation))
                                .Cast<int>()
                                .ToDictionary(enumValue => enumValue, 
                                              enumValue => Enum.GetName(typeof(Translation), enumValue));
```

**Note**: If your enum's type isn't `int`, for example it enum's type is `byte`, you may use `Cast<byte>()` instead of `Cast<int>()`

Answer (score 3):

***I didn't read the question carefully, so my code will not work in C# 1.0 as it utilises generics. Best use it with >= C# 4.0 (>= VS2010)***

To make life easier, I've created this helper service.

The usage for the service is as follows:

```
// create an instance of the service (or resolve it using DI)
var svc = new EnumHelperService();

// call the MapEnumToDictionary method (replace TestEnum1 with your enum)
var result = svc.MapEnumToDictionary<TestEnum1>();
```

The service code is as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// This service provides helper methods for enums.
/// </summary>
public interface IEnumHelperService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Maps the enum to dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Dictionary<int, string> MapEnumToDictionary<T>();
}

/// <summary>
/// This service provides helper methods for enums.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="Panviva.Status.Probe.Lib.Services.IEnumHelperService" />
public class EnumHelperService : IEnumHelperService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EnumHelperService"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public EnumHelperService()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Maps the enum to dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">T must be an enumerated type</exception>
    public Dictionary<int, string> MapEnumToDictionary<T>() 
    {
        // Ensure T is an enumerator
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerator type.");
        }

        // Return Enumertator as a Dictionary
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToDictionary(i => (int)Convert.ChangeType(i, i.GetType()), t => t.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Question specifically asks for C# 1.0 answers, yours make use of version 2.0 (generics) and 3.0 (`var`) features?

Comment: My bad, didn't see that.

Answer (score 3):

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(DirectionEnum)).Cast<int>().Select(p => new { id = p,name=((DirectionEnum)p).ToString() }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version.  Feels more straightforward to me than any of the suggestions above but maybe I'm missing something:

```
Enum.GetValues<SomeEnum>().Select(g => new KeyValuePair<int, string>((int)g, g.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from the answer by @jamie

Place this into a static extension class then do 
`typeof(Translation).ToValueList<int>();`

```
    /// <summary>
    /// If an enum MyEnum is { a = 3, b = 5, c = 12 } then
    /// typeof(MyEnum).ToValueList<<int>>() will return [3, 5, 12]
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumType"></param>
    /// <returns>List of values defined for enum constants</returns>
    public static List<T> ToValueList<T>(this Type enumType)
    {
        return Enum.GetNames(enumType)
            .Select(x => (T)Enum.Parse(enumType, x))
            .ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var enumType = typeof(Translation);
var objList = enumValuesList.Select(v =>
{
    var i =  (Translation)Enum.Parse(enumType, v);
    return new
    {
        Id = (int)i,
        Value = v
    };
});
```